# Fill progress bar in x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code...

HTML

```
<div class="progress-bar">
    <span class="progress-bar-fill" style="width: 30%"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progress-bar {
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height: 5px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.progress-bar-fill {
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background: #659cef;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

It's supposed to show the progress of slider and how long the current image will last till the next one apperas....

If the image changes every 5 seconds, then I want the bar to fill out 100% in 5 seconds... I'm total noob in javascript and jQuery...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use it.

**Update :-**
make `transition` 5 second.

`transition: width 5s ease-in-out;`

```js
$('.progress-bar-fill').delay(1000).queue(function () {
        $(this).css('width', '100%')
    });
```

```css
.progress-bar {
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height: 5px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.progress-bar-fill {
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background: #659cef;
    border-radius: 3px;
    /*transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;*/
    transition: width 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar">
    <span class="progress-bar-fill" style="width: 30%"></span>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: sorry but thats not it... I don't want the animation to happen after 5 seconds and then just fill up in one... I want the filling process to last 5 seconds straight away...

Answer (score 5):

You could have your jQuery set the transition declaration in one shot.

To fill in 5s:

`$(".progress-bar-fill").css({"width":"100%","transition":"5s"});`

To empty instantly:

`$(".progress-bar-fill").css({"width":"0%","transition":"none"});`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fill-5 {
    animation: fill 5s linear 1;
}
.fill-4 {
    animation: fill 4s linear 1;
}
.fill-3 {
    animation: fill 3s linear 1;
}
.fill-2 {
    animation: fill 2s linear 1;
}
.fill-1 {
    animation: fill 1s linear 1;
}
@keyframes fill {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.progress {
    --bs-progress-height: 1rem;
    --bs-progress-font-size: 0.75rem;
    --bs-progress-bg: #e9ecef;
    --bs-progress-border-radius: 0.375rem;
    --bs-progress-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    --bs-progress-bar-color: #fff;
    --bs-progress-bar-bg: #0d6efd;
    --bs-progress-bar-transition: width 0.6s ease;
    display: flex;
    height: var(--bs-progress-height);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: var(--bs-progress-font-size);
    background-color: var(--bs-progress-bg);
    border-radius: var(--bs-progress-border-radius);
}
.progress-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: var(--bs-progress-bar-color);
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: var(--bs-progress-bar-bg);
    transition: var(--bs-progress-bar-transition);
}
```

```html
Fill in 5 second
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar fill-5" role="progressbar"
        style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
Fill in 4 second
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar fill-4" role="progressbar"
        style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
Fill in 3 second
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar fill-3" role="progressbar"
        style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
Fill in 2 second
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar fill-2" role="progressbar"
        style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
Fill in 1 second
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar fill-1" role="progressbar"
        style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO & Thanks. While this code may solve the OP's issue, "answers" without an explanation or links to documentation are frowned upon on SO. Quality answers help coders learn & understand why some code works & other code doesn't. Over time, as visitors learn something that they can apply to their own coding issues, quality answers tend to accrue more upvotes. Consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74456947/edit) your answer with context or an explanation how/why your code solves the OP's issue, or how it differs from other answers (& why), or why OP's code didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could do this:

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
 #container {
 margin: 20px;
 width: 400px;
 height: 8px;
 position: relative;
 }
```

Babel + JSX

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
strokeWidth: 4,
easing: 'easeInOut',
duration: 1400,
color: '#FFEA82',
trailColor: '#eee',
trailWidth: 1,
svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
text: {
style: {
  // Text color.
  // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
  color: '#999',
  position: 'absolute',
  right: '0',
  top: '30px',
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  transform: null
},
autoStyleContainer: false
},
from: {color: '#FFEA82'},
to: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
step: (state, bar) => {
bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 100) + ' %');
}
});

bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

It can all tun on https://jsfiddle.net 
Cheers!